# xslt 2.0: consecutively add values of preceding nodes

Tags: xml, addition, xslt-2.0

lets say I have the following source:

```
<root>
    <initialAmount>1000</initialAmount>
    <Amortization_List>
        <Amortization Index="0">10</Amortization>
        <Amortization Index="1">25</Amortization>
        <Amortization Index="2">-10</Amortization>
    </Amortization_List>
</root>
```

Now, I want to add to the `initialAmount` the nodes `Amortization` consecutively, so my output looks something like this:

```
<result>
    <amount>1010</amount>
    <amount>1035</amount>
    <amount>1025</amount>
</result>
```

How can I do this in xslt 2.0?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <result>
    <xsl:variable name="amount" select="initialAmount"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Amortization_List/Amortization[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$amount"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Amortization">
  <xsl:param name="sum"/>
  <xsl:variable name="amount" select=". + $sum"/>
  <amount><xsl:value-of select="$amount"/></amount>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Amortization[1]">
    <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$amount"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is not completely what I need. Your solution adds the value of each node to the initial amount, but I want it to be added to the previous sum.

Comment: @user2986852, I have changed the code to address your problem.

Comment: Thanks, it works! It is beyond my understanding how it does it but I will try to figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: Note there is a small error in it: </xsl:with-param> should be </xsl:apply-templates>, but I have no rights to edit your posting.

Comment: Sorry about the incorrect closing tag, now corrected. As for how it works, we start with the first `Amortization` and then use the `following-sibling` axis to step by step compute the values you are looking for, passing on the current value as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I understand the concept now. However, this is still unclear: Why does `following-sibling::Amortization[1]` not access node nr. 2 every time, but goes forward every time?